# error CS5001: Program `main.exe' does not contain a static `Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

```
 using System;

class Program {
  static string Main(){
    string Input = Console.ReadLine();
    return Input;
  }
  static int Health () {
    int Health = 100;
    return Health;
  }
static int EnemyHealth(){
  int EnemyHealth = 100;
  return EnemyHealth;
}
static int y(){
  int y = 0;
  if (Main() == "d"){
    y++;
    if (y == 11){
      y=10;
    }
  }
  if (Main() == "a"){
    y--;
    if (y == -1){
      y=0;
    }
  }
  return y;
}
static int x(){
  int x = 0;
  if (Main() == "w"){
    x--;
    if (x == -1){
      x=0;
    }
  }
  if (Main() == "s"){
    x++;
    if (x == 11){
      x=10;
    }
  }
  return x;
  }
}
```

I am trying to make a game that moves your character on repl with y and x cordinates but i get this error error CS5001: Program `main.exe' does not contain a static` Main' method suitable for an entry point. Btw this was made in replit. Please help!!!!!!

Comment: `Main` should not return a string. It's `void` or `int`

Answer (score 2):

The Main() method has an expected signature (its name, arguments, and return type ect..). In your case you're using `static string Main()` which is not an allowable signature yet.

Per [MSDN pertaining the Main() signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/)

> Main can either have a void, int, or, starting with C# 7.1, Task, or Task return type.
> If and only if Main returns a Task or Task, the declaration of Main may include the async modifier. Note that this specifically excludes an async void Main method.